# Help installing some Java and Flash

Tags: installation, java, google-chrome, flash

I have Git now and some other stuff, but I've looked around and all and I don't get very helpful information. I've used these instructions:

1. Download the latest version of Flash Player from the Adobe Website.
   Click on **Download the Latest Player** and choose ".deb for Ubuntu" from the dropdown list.
2. Choose "Save File" from the pop up window.
3. Open a terminal window.
   The terminal window will be found under Applications -> Utilities.
4. Change to the directory where your downloaded file was saved.
   `cd Downloads`
5. Install the libcurl3 library.
   sudo apt-get install libcurl3
6. Install the Flash Player.
   `sudo dpkg --install install_flash_player_<version>_linux.deb`
   Replace  with the latest version number.
7. Restart Firefox.
8. Check that Flash Player was installed.
   Type `about:plugins` in a browser window, and look for the Flash Player MIME type.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_5068467_install-flash-player-ubuntu.html#ixzz2ixPj47qS

What I don't understand is how I change the directory and all that crap which they say everyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Open **Terminal**

2 - Copy & Paste Command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

3 - Press **Enter**

4 - Type in your username

5 - Press **Enter**

You have not just installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras, one part of that is Flash.

[Ubuntu Restricted Extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

To install Java, please follow the instructions:

[Easy Linux Tips: Installing Java](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

Answer (score 0):

I am using very easy procedure (I think):

1. Download flash player .tar.gz
2. Extract it and you can see usr and libflashplayer.so
3. Now use this command (in folder where you have extracted usr and libflash...) for copy usr on his place

> sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
>
> Copy libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins with this command (in folder where you have extracted usr and libflash...)
>
> > sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins

Answer (score 0):

## Flash

Adapted from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash

> ### Ubuntu (32-bit)
>
> 1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
> 2. Search for 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'
> 3. Install the package (this package also installs MP3 and WMV codecs)
>
> ### Ubuntu (64-bit)
>
> 1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
> 2. Search for 'flashplugin-installer'
> 3. Install the package (if you are asked to uninstall previous Flash Player plugins, click OK)

## Java

The instructions are a bit more complicated. Here's the official help guide, which is probably the guide you want to follow to get the end-user version of java: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

As a developer, I prefer manually managing my java installation. I need the jdk and I actively avoid the security disaster that is the java web plugin. I typically need several versions of Oracle's jdk installed. Fortunately Oracle offers a tarball on their website. Extract it wherever you want and set your `$JAVA_HOME`.